# Is Intel XDK open source?

Tags: html, intel-xdk

Please let me know whether Intel XDK is an open source or not?

To what extent it can support HTML5 and for smart devices?

Comment: 2017 Update - Intel XDK has been discontinued !

Answer (score 12):

**Intel XDK** tool itself is **not** open sourced, Intel XDK is an Integrated Development Environment (IDE) for building cross-platform apps using HTML5. The tool itself is built using various **Open source projects** like [**node-webkit**](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) for the native shell, Adobe [Brackets](https://github.com/adobe/brackets) for the code editor, [Apache Ripple](http://ripple.incubator.apache.org/) for the emulator, and other technologies.

It supports building native packaged apps for iOS, Android, Windows Phone, Tizen and other devices. It supports building apps that use [**Cordova**](http://cordova.apache.org/) APIs for these devices and also supports building apps with [**Crosswalk**](https://crosswalk-project.org/) for Android.

Answer (score 4):

XDK is not open sourced however it is free. Intel supports it to empower HTML5 and promote usage of HTML5.

XDK is supporting lots of HTML5 codes and it is working very fine at least in IOS, Android and Windows Phone. With XDK you can make hybrid apps which has lots of native apps features. You can use geolocation, client side database, phone camera , push messages and many other things in these hybrid apps. Advantage of XDK is its powerful emulator and debugging. You can easily emulate your codes in different devices from HTC phones to Nokia, iPhone and Samsung. apart of emulator they released an app in Google play and apple store for debugging your app without need of build and install the app on your phone. just need to download App Preview from App Store or Google Play or Windows Store. You can check their app [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/app-preview-overview)

Apart of that build process is so easy. You can easily build an app for different platforms. You just needt to write your code with JS+html5+css3. If you need PHP and MySQL in your mobile app, you can easily connect your client side code to the server side by AJAX. Also INTEL supports App Framework which is a great library of codes made on base of jquery and facilitate the development significantly.

I made several apps with XDK and am very satisfied and recommend it to you.

Answer (score 1):

App Framework is also part of the Intel XDK and is an open source project you can contribute to:

```
https://github.com/01org/appframework
```

or learn more about:

```
http://app-framework-software.intel.com/
```

Answer (score -3):

Intel XDK is open source you can download the following link
https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-xdk

And also read the documenation about intel xdk see the below link
https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/lp-index

Intel xdk is opensource to build hybrid mobile applications,it supports android devices and iphone and windows phone using bootstrap and jquery and html5 and javascript and aslo support cordova.

By using intel xdk we can easily develop apps and debuging and testing the apps.
it's absoultely free.

Comment: Intel XDK is free, but it is not open source.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.